# Shared preferences and explicit intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences, explicit-intent

Hi to anyone who can answer,

So I came across this question (it was an assignment, I already submitted it anyways). It was regarding shared preferences and explicit intents. I know both can pass data (through putString, putExtra, putInt etc and getExtra, getString, getInt). However which method is better to pass data and why? It can be in terms of functionality or just how much lesser the codes are when comparing each method to each other.

Comment: Forgot to add, which is a better choice to use when passing data between 2 activities?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data when transitioning from one activity to another activity, then it's normally better to use [intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to pass data.

However if you want the data you are passing to still be retrievable after the user exit your app and reopen it, then you should use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Intent is better to use when you are passing data when you are going from one activity to another. Otherwise, you should use SharedPreferences instead. And as mentioned above, if you want the data to be stored and retrievable even when the user reopens the app, then you should always go with a [storage option](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) like SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

those are two completely different functionalities that should not be mixed.

- `Intent` extras are used to pass data from one activity to another. If the intention is having one activity put data and the next one receive you should use Intent extras
- `SharedPreferences` is a very lightweight data storage. It's meant to store data on permanent memory and can be retrieved by any entity within your app. If you need data to be saved and access any moment in the future from anywhere in your app, you should use this.